# Forcing HTTPS and www on All Traffic using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I only have the access to cPanel and .htaacess file. I want non-www to www and http to https as one. I want to redirect the website in the following manner.

```
http://example.co.uk/       >     https://www.example.co.uk/   // https and www

http://www.example.co.uk/   >     https://www.example.co.uk/   // https

https://example.co.uk/      >     https://www.example.co.uk/   // www

https://www.example.co.uk/  >     https://www.example.co.uk/   // ok
```

The redirection should also work for **all traffic in that domain (home page and links)**. And It should not redirected to `301` because of SEO. But I want directly to `https` and `www`.

Currently I have the following htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It works fine. But two times redirected with 301 for `http://example.co.uk`.

Comment: Rule that you've shown will redirect only once. Are you sure you don't have some `http->https` setting via cpanel?

Comment: Yeah! no there on cPanel

Answer (score 0):

You may try this one

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Source: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-redirect-http-to-https-using-htaccess/